# Easiest timestamp type to use when grabbing rows from a certain period?

Tags: mysql, datetime, unix-timestamp

I have a column in a table which I want to update automatically whenever the rows changes or when I first insert it. I had set it to using the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` function as I found this the easiest when I wanted to get all rows that are at least a week old or is there an easier/better method.

I could use the `datetime` or `timestamp` types but I wasn't sure how to retrieve the rows that are 7 days old or older.

I understand I just set the `DEFAULT` setting to the respective function such as `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` to update it automatically!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to have your column like this:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(
whatever_id int auto_increment,
myTS timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY(whatever_id)
);
```

This way whenever you something in the row, myTS is automatically updated with the current date. The default value of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is optionally. Only drawback is that MySQL only allows one column in a table to have `DEFAULT` or `ON UPDATE` to have `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. But there exist workarounds and that leads too far now. Ask if you need to know.

Then when you want to have rows that are 7 days or older, you do

```
SELECT
*
FROM foo
WHERE
DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), myTS) >= 7
/*or
DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), myTS) >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
*/
```

Read more about `DATEDIFF` function [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff).

Or another way is

```
SELECT
*
FROM foo
WHERE
DATE_ADD(myTS, INTERVAL 1 WEEK) <= CURDATE()
```

You can read more about `DATE_ADD` function under the same link as above.

Of course it's also possible to simply pick the date by hand:

```
SELECT
*
FROM foo
WHERE
myTS < '2012-07-02'
```

But note, that a `timestamp` column consists of date **and** time value. So when you write something like query above it's implicitly `'2012-07-02 00:00:00'`. So if you want to have something like `<= 2012-07-02 (the whole day)` you have to write `<= '2012-07-02 23:59:59'`. Wanted to add that, just in case this leads to confusion.